# Build static dropdown menu for simple search Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

I have a simple search working in my rails app, but it only searches a single column of my table. I'm trying to add a simple dropdown menu with options like "last_name" and "city" so the user can select the column to search.

In my view I have:

```
<%= form_tag teachers_path, :method => 'get', :id => "teachers_search" do %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :direction, params[:direction]%>
<%= hidden_field_tag :sort, params[:sort]%>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: 'First Name' %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :first_name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

and in my model:

```
 def self.search(search)
    if search
      where('first_name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a select_tag for your drop down menu

```
<%= select_tag "search_from", "<option>first_name</option><option>last_name</option><option>city_name</option>".html_safe%>
```

In your controller you can pass the value in params[:search_from] to your search method. and modify it to include the column name

```
def self.search(search, column_name)
  if search
    where('? LIKE ?', column_name, "%#{search}%")
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

I've written it in a crude way but i hope it gets the message along.

Comment: I'm agreed with your approach, but  select_tag were bit odd...i've tried to fix it

Comment: Yes. Wrote it really quickly. Mentioned in the last line :)  Just wanted to convey the idea along.

Comment: @sohaibbbhatti : Thanks I was looking for this only.. you save my time. ;)

Answer (score 1):

extending @sohaibs's answer dropdown is a good idea if you are only allowing user to filter result with some some fixed attributes

**views**

```
<%= select_tag "search_by", options_for_select(['first_name','last_name','city'].map{|o| [o.humanize,o] }) %>
<%= f.text_field 'search' %>
```

**controller**

```
def search
  User.search params[:teacher][:search_by],params[:teacher][:search]
end
```

and **model**

```
def self.search(search_by,search_value)
     where('? LIKE ?', search_by, search_value)
end
```

Awesome Rails  :)

Comment: Thanks. This all makes sense, but I'm getting a "ArgumentError in Teachers#index, wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)" error message that I can't seem to work through. Is this missing an argument somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
def self.search(column, search)
  # some logic
  where('? LIKE ?', column, "%#{search}%")
  # some logic
end
```